# How to make fs writeFile faster for an image?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I make this faster? I am using node and fs library. This is the endpoint of a POST request that sends an fs.Readable stream of a jpg image. The code is starting to hang at just around the 800 kB mark. Eventually, I want to be able to save a video. Ideally, I want it to take less than ten seconds.

```
  var bufs = [];
  readStream.on('data', function(d){ bufs.push(d); });
  readStream.on('end', function(){
  var buf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
  console.log(buf);
  fs.writeFile("test.jpg", buf, ()=>{console.log('hi')});
  });
```

Comment: Do you want the writing to take less than 10 seconds or for a response to go back to the client in less than 10 seconds?

Comment: The writing, there's other stuff i want to do server side before I send anything back to the client, but I don't want to wait forever.

Comment: Write it directly as you read it - skip the additional processing steps: `readableStream.pipe(writableStream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way that also uses less memory and parallelizes the writes (writes chunks as they arrive) and should be a bit faster would be to just pipe the stream directly to the output file.

```
readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("test.jpg"));
readStream.on('close', () => {
    console.log("all done now");
});
```

Or, with better error handling that would catch errors on both streams and tell you when everything was done:

```
const { pipeline } = require('stream');

pipeline(readStream, fs.createWriteStream("test.jpg"), err => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("all done");
    }
});
```

Or, using promises and `pipeline()`:

```
const pipeline = util.promisify(require('stream').pipeline);

pipeline(readStream, fs.createWriteStream("test.jpg")).then(() => {
   console.log("all done");
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! Unfortunately, it seems I asked the wrong question. It runs fast enough, it just freezes at the end. I printed each data chunk as it is read in, and it gets to the end, it just doesn't trigger the end function. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @QrowSaki - I looked at the [source for the `pipeline()` implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/streams/end-of-stream.js#L145) and it uses another file called end-of-stream which hooks up to `close`, `finish` and `end` events and indicates that different types of streams use different events.  If this is an `http.IncomingMessage ` stream, then it looks like it should give you a `end` and then a `close` event.

Comment: @QrowSaki - When I run a test in my own http server with event handlers for `end`, `finish` and `close` on the incoming req object, I only get the `close` event so perhaps that's the one you should be using.  Streams are so general purpose and used in so many ways that some things they are just not very consistent and not documented at all.  This appears to be one of those things.

Comment: I get 'end' and 'close' for anything less than 800kB. I get nothing for anything over that. Could you try playing with file size on your server too? See if it changes anything? Thank you for all the help regardless. You have been extremely helpful!

Comment: @QrowSaki - On my test server, I just hooked into an exist form post - I don't have control over the size of the upload.  What middleware are you using to parse the incoming upload?  Does it have configured size limits?

Comment: @QrowSaki - If I look in front of my middleware that reads the body, then I also get both `end` and `close`.

Comment: I am using express. There may be a limit, actually, you're probably right. I'm having trouble finding a way to increase the limit. What middleware did you use?