# fs writeFile freezes before finishes writing file

Tags: javascript, node.js, filestream

My code runs instantaneously for 600kB files...700kB files, at 800kB it suddenly hangs and doesn't get to the end.

I printed out each time it writes a chunk to the buffer.
(The 65536 is 2^16, presumably size of each chunk.)

```
  var bufs = [];
  var count = 0;
  readStream.on('data', function(d){ bufs.push(d); 
    count += 65536;
    console.log(count/1000 + "k" + "/ 800k");
  });
  readStream.on('end', function(){
  var buf = Buffer.concat(bufs);
  console.log(buf);
  fs.writeFile("test.jpg", buf, ()=>{console.log('hi')});
  });
```

And I get this:

```
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  65.536k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  131.072k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  196.608k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  262.144k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  327.68k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  393.216k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  458.752k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  524.288k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  589.824k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  655.36k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  720.896k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  786.432k/ 800k
5:04:02 PM web.1 |  851.968k/ 800k
```

Which means it gets to the end, but the `readStream.on('end'...` isn't triggered. So the actual fs writeFile doesn't actually happen.

Previously, I asked a question [How to make fs writeFile faster for an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64795981/how-to-make-fs-writefile-faster-for-an-image) because I thought it was hanging because I was doing it inefficiently. I got some good answers about writing directly from the read stream, and not bothering with the buffer (thanks @jfriend00 and @Randy Casburn):

```
readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream("test.jpg"));
readStream.on('end', () => {
    console.log("all done now");
});
```

But it still hangs, same exact behavior, at around 800kB size.

Comment: What middleware do you have on this readStream that is parsing it for you?  Does it have configured size limits or default size limits?

Comment: I'm using express. I don't know if that counts as a middleware. If it's not, then I don't have a middleware that's parsing it for me. I'm directly getting a readStream. Do I need a middleware for that? What middleware do you recommend?

Comment: Express is not middleware.  It's the framework into which you insert middleware.  If this is a file upload via an http request, the raw stream is not your direct file contents.  The raw stream has to be parsed and decoded into your file contents as it will typically be a content-type like ` multipart/form-data` which has to be parsed and decoded.  You would typically use some middleware such as [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to parse the data.  Multer also has options to directly put the parsed data into a file for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try multer and see if it works.

Comment: It may be caused by OS. You should check same thing on different environment with same node version first.

Comment: @OlegImanilov can you elaborate? It suddenly started working (same environment) and I don't know why. What about the OS could make it behave this way?

Comment: Most chances it is related to security software (antivirus) which may run totally in memory for smaller files, but start to use IO when files a bit larger. When you writing to fs, actually it going through  tmp-write -> read&check -> actual-write by antivirus.